# How to do a foreach loop in PHP with three dynamic form elements?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a form that prepopulate some database information, and I want that same form to save the new information if the user modifies that.

The form have three elements to be saved: **roleID**, **nombreRol** and **detallesRol**

I'm using a **foreach** loop to get the information, but I just get the roleID and the nombreRol into the foreach, and not the third field. What am I doing wrong?

(Please note that I've not taken into consideration security yet, it's just a proof of concept at the moment).

### I show a list of input items

```
    $mostrarRoles = mysqli_query($conectar,$buscarRoles);
        while ($roles=mysqli_fetch_array($mostrarRoles)) {
            echo '<br><div class="form-group">
                Role ID: '.$roles['roleID'].' <b>'.$roles['nombreRol'].'</b> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreRol['.$roles['roleID'].']" value="'.$roles['nombreRol'].'">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="detallesRol[]" rows="2">'.$roles['detallesRol'].'</textarea>
                ';              
        }
```

### Now, I put the information inside a foreach loop:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $rol = $_POST['nombreRol'];
    foreach ($rol as $key => $value) {
        $roleID = $key;
        $nombreRol = $value;
        echo 'ID '.$roleID.'<br>';
        echo 'Name '.$nombreRol.'<br>';
        echo 'Details '.$detallesRol.'<br>';

            $guardarRoles = "    UPDATE roles
                                 SET    nombreRol = '$nombreRol', 
                                        detallesRol = '$detallesRol'
                                 WHERE roleID = '$roleID'
                                ";
    }
...
```

When I echo the roleID and the nombreRol variables they do show the user input (and it gets saved to the database), but not the details.

I know that I'm constructing wrong the foreach, how may I correct it?

Comment: If detallesRol is an array, can't you just use detallesRol[$key]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `$detallesRol`variable is not defined.

Every value of `$roles['detallesRol']` is stored in `$_POST['detallesRol']`.

So your html output should be changed to

```
// add roleID as a key
<textarea class="form-control" name="detallesRol[' . $roles['roleID'] . ']" rows="2">'.$roles['detallesRol'].'</textarea>
```

And in `foreach`:

```
foreach ($rol as $key => $value) {
    $roleID = $key;
    $nombreRol = $value;
    $detallesRol = $_POST['detallesRol'][$roleID];
    echo 'Details '.$detallesRol.'<br>';
    // Do update
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately neither `$_POST['detallesRol'][$roleID]` nor `$_POST['detallesRol'][$key]`, won't work, they are blank (I did change the html output.

Comment: So `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Still not defined: `Array ( [nombreRol] => Array ( [1] => admin [2] => noAutorizado) [detallesRol] => [nuevoRol] => [submit] => Guardar Cambios )`

Comment: Check your full form. Error can be somewhere else. I suppose that you have field for `nuevoRol` and it's description has name `detallesRol` (which is the same as existing fields)?